# can't install ruby on m1 macbook air

Tags: ruby

I tried every method to install ruby (rvm, rbenv, brew) how do I install ruby on m1 MBA?

I used brew to install ruby

```
dipanshukashyap@Dipanshus-MacBook-Air ~ % brew install ruby
Warning: ruby 3.2.2_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.2.2_1, run:
  brew reinstall ruby
dipanshukashyap@Dipanshus-MacBook-Air ~ % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
```

it installed ruby but when I check version it gives old version

I used rbenv it gave same problem. (installed, made it global by `rbenv global 3.2.2`  after installation as instructed but when checked, gives older version)

I used RVM it gives `Error running '__rvm_make -j8'`

Comment: You seem to have multiple Ruby versions installed and the system is defaulting to an older one. Try adding this to the beginning of your .zshrc (or .bashrc) profile: `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"`. Open a new terminal, then verify the change with `which ruby`. Then check `ruby -v` again. Let us know if that works.

Comment: When you run `brew install ruby`, read the installation messages! It told you that ruby wasn’t added to the PATH because it might collide with the system’s ruby, and told you how to change that if you want. After installation you can re-view those caveats using `brew info ruby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Homebrew Rubies

Don't do what you're doing. It will eventually cause bad things to happen. Just don't.

If you insist on juggling chainsaws, then you should create an alias or function to wrap your calls to Ruby in interactive sessions rather than fooling around with the system Ruby, especially in non-interactive shells.

For example, you can add the following to your ~/.zshrc if you want:

```bash
alias ruby="$(brew --prefix ruby)/bin/ruby"
```

This approach won't make rvm think it manages that particular Ruby version, but might make it think it's your system Ruby. In any event, you can call the Ruby you think you're calling by putting it first in your *PATH*.

### RVM Rubies

The right way to do this is to install Ruby in your home directory (not a system directory) using a Ruby version manager such as RVM. To do that:

1. [Install RVM using the single-user method.](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#installation-explained)
2. Make sure your shell initialization files are set up properly. This doesn't always happen if you're an advanced user who makes a lot of changes to setup files.
3. Start a new shell, or call `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to [load RVM in the current shell](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#3-reload-shell-configuration-amp-test).
4. Install whatever rubies RVM currently supports with `rvm list known`. See [Installing Rubies](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing) for more specifics, especially if you're trying to install a patched or non-standard version. *NB: Ruby 3.2.2 is still the latest [non-preview release](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/) that I'm aware of as of this writing.*

RVM, chruby, and rbenv are all good options, and will save you from permissions issues and broken OS dependencies caused by changing the system Ruby or using a brewed binary that may still require additional changes to your environment to work properly. The version managers, when properly installed, avoid those issues for you.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the command I copied from a random answer on github, so apologies for that.
I ran the command
`rvm install ruby-3.2.2 --with-openssl-dir='/opt/local'`
(newer version)
Anyways, I ran `rvm install 3.2.2` from home directory as you said and it says `Already installed ruby-3.2.2.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-3.2.2`
everything's working fine right now, should I be concerned?

Comment: @DeepanshuKashyap If it's working fine, maybe not, but without a lot more debugging I have no idea which Ruby rvm is picking up. Personally, I'd switch to the system Ruby with `rvm use system`, remove the brewed Ruby with `brew uninstall ruby`, and then reinstall the version you want under rvm to make sure your gems and other things aren't using system directories or Rubies in your *PATH*. Alternatively, just reinstall with rvm and make sure you source it last in your shell init scripts. Things *can* work fine with a brewed Ruby, but in your particular case I'd say "better safe than sorry."